# Getting the value of a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I ave the following `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Margin="5" SelectedValue="{Binding NewCourseWeekday, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">
    <ComboBoxItem>Monday</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Tuesday</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Wednesday</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Thursday</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Friday</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

And I have the setter/getter:

```
public String NewCourseWeekday
{
    get { return _newCourseWeekday; }
    set
    {
        _newCourseWeekday = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

But, if I try to use this `_newCourseWeekday`, it doesn't just contain the weekday, but it contains something like `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Monday`. How can I select the string only?

Comment: you mean in the setter? I cannot compile that, there's no such variable as `text`.

Comment: Try adding `SelectedValuePath="Content"` to the ComboBox element. If that works, use mm8's answer instead anyway. It better illustrates how to do things in WPF.

Comment: Mode=TwoWay is the default for bindings on ComboBox.SelectedValue, no need to tell it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying that the selected value is the actual content of your item and not the ComboBoxItem itself, you should be able to get the string like you expect to. For this, use the `SelectedValuePath` property, and set it to `Content`.

```
<ComboBox Margin="5" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="{Binding NewCourseWeekday}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1">
    <ComboBoxItem>Monday</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Tuesday</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Wednesday</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Thursday</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Friday</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `string` objects to the `ComboBox` and bind its `SelectedItem` property to your `NewCourseWeekday` source property:

```
<ComboBox Margin="5" SelectedItem="{Binding NewCourseWeekday, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"
          xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <s:String>Monday</s:String>
    <s:String>Tuesday</s:String>
    <s:String>Wednesday</s:String>
    <s:String>Thursday</s:String>
    <s:String>Friday</s:String>
</ComboBox>
```

A `string` property cannot be set to a `ComboBoxItem` value.

Answer (score -1):

You have to bind NewCourseWeekday to the SelectedItem and not to the SelectedValue

Comment: That didn't help.